# Parse-Server Cloud-Code and Stripe

Tags: node.js, heroku, stripe-payments, parse-cloud-code, parse-server

I'm running a Parse-Server instance for a mobile web-app on Heroku. My problem is Stripe checkout plugin is working fine in my html page, but when the token is created and I call my Cloud Code it seems as if creating the variable initializing stripe does nothing. This is my cloud code.

```
var stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_******');
Parse.Cloud.define("pay", function(req, res){
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var token = req.params.token;
    var amount = req.params.amount;
    var email = req.params.email;
    // stripe is null
    res.success(stripe);
});
```

Upon calling this, the value of stripe is null and I cannot figure out why. I have added stripe: '~4.7.0' in my package.json file and have run npm install to locally create all node modules. I don't know if it makes a difference but in my index.js file I have created a router

```
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
```

because it's easier to access files in the public directory this way. Otherwise I would have to reference files in my public directory with /public/filename everytime I wanted to include that file. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Move `var stripe` inside the "pay" function. I am currently using it this way and it works.

Comment: I just tried that to no avail. For some reason I just cannot initialize stripe in Cloud Code. I can do it in index.js though. I can initialize any other package that was included in package.json initially, but not ones I've added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up trying to run this charge in Cloud Code. Instead I created a route '/charge' in my index.js file and called it using a jQuery post. Here is my code in index.js

```
var stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_****');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
app.post('/charge', function(req, res){
    var token = req.body.token;
    var amount = req.body.amount;
    stripe.charges.create({
        amount: amount,
        currency: 'usd',
        source: token,
    }, function(err, charge){
        if(err)
            // Error check
        else
            res.send('Payment successful!');
    }
});
```

Here is my jQuery request

```
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: 'pk_test_****',
    locale: 'auto',
    token: function(token){
        $.post('/charge', {
            token: token.id,
            amount: total,
        }, function(data, status){
            alert(data);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

i had issues with this today

I did it by trial and error, here is what i remember

https://www.npmjs.com/package/stripe <- thats where i got the cloud code from

1. in the root directory of your parse-server through command prompt i executed the following - **npm install stripe**
2. then i added the stripe dependancy to package.json (this stack overflow post was the missing key) **"stripe": "~4.9.0",**
3. the cloud code is as follows

Parse.Cloud.define("charge", function(request, response) {

```
var stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_****');

stripe.customers.create({
  email: theEmailAddress
}).then(function(customer) {
  return stripe.charges.create({
    amount: yourAmount, 
    currency: yourCurrency,
    card: yourToken,
    description: yourDescription
  });
}).then(function(charge) {
  // New charge created on a new customer 
}).catch(function(err) {
  // Deal with an error 
});
```

});

4. use that cloud code through your app and see if it works in your stripe dashboard (you must check in the dashboard)

so the two 'breakthroughs' came when i added stripe as a dependancy in package.json and also can you see that `var stripe = require` is inside the the cloud code function

see the following post where the answer was originally posted

[Require modul not working when I migrate from parse to heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38890120/require-modul-not-working-when-i-migrate-from-parse-to-heroku/38897824#38897824)