# Require modul not working when I migrate from parse to heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, parse-server

I migrated from parse to heroku and I am trying to get cloud code to work. Everything works fine when the cloud code file is blank, but when I add the require Stripe or Twilio lines in the main.js file, nothing in my app loads. What am I doing wrong?

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"express": "~4.11.x",
"kerberos": "~0.0.x",
"parse": "~1.8.0",
"parse-server": "~2.2.12",
"stripe": "~4.9.0",
"twilio": "~2.9.2"
}
```

main.js

```
var Stripe = require('stripe');
Stripe.initialize('sk_test_xxxxxxx');
```

Comment: Are you getting any feedback from Heroku when you push your code?  Normally if there's a module problem you'll see it in STDOUT after your `git push heroku master`.  Similarly, can you post the output of heroku logs (`heroku logs -a <your app name>`) here to aid in debugging?

Comment: It successfully pushes to heroku

Comment: @Paul seems like I am getting errors XD https://puu.sh/qxhmH/142a99ce11.png

Comment: Can you check if you see the same error when you are trying to require only Twilio ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had issues with this today

I did it by trial and error, here is what i remember

https://www.npmjs.com/package/stripe <- thats where i got the cloud code from

1. in the root directory of your parse-server through command prompt i executed the following - **npm install stripe**
2. then i added the stripe dependancy to package.json (this stack overflow post was the missing key) **"stripe": "~4.9.0",**
3. the cloud code is as follows

Parse.Cloud.define("charge", function(request, response) {

```
var stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_****');

stripe.customers.create({
  email: theEmailAddress
}).then(function(customer) {
  return stripe.charges.create({
    amount: yourAmount, 
    currency: yourCurrency,
    card: yourToken,
    description: yourDescription
  });
}).then(function(charge) {
  // New charge created on a new customer 
}).catch(function(err) {
  // Deal with an error 
});
```

});

4. use that cloud code through your app and see if it works in your stripe dashboard (you must check in the dashboard)

so the two 'breakthroughs' came when i added stripe as a dependancy in package.json and also can you see that `var stripe = require` is inside the the cloud code function